# Does drupal cache the settings?

Tags: database

I've been given a Drupal site to put on our server, I've not worked with Drupal before. From my understanding, the database credentials are stored in the settings.php file:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'foo',
      'username' => 'foo',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I've updated these to use the new server credentials (from `foo` to `bar` for the sake of this post). However it's failing to connect, with the error showing that it's still using the old credentials, `foo`.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'bar',
      'username' => 'bar',
      'password' => 'newpassword',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'foo'@'0.0.0.0' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home/sites/bar/public_html/includes/lock.inc).
```

So my question, does Drupal store these credentials anywhere else or cache them?

Comment: No i've never experiences these settings being cached. Are you certain you've updated the correct file and it saved ok? The settings.php file might be read only so your change didnt actually save

Comment: You have to give the 'host' => 'localhost', to server host

Comment: It's definitely using the updated credentials on the server. If you're querying the localhost because of the `0.0.0.0` IP, that's because I changed it to 0.0.0.0 for the example.

Comment: Most people don't use the settings file directly, they use a local.settings, or include an environment specific file. Check the rest of setting.php to see if something else is being included, or if the details are duplicated further down.

Comment: There is another settings file overriding the one you’re looking at. You can tell which one is loaded by dropping an exit at the top and reloading. You should get a white screen.

Comment: You're right @Kevin, i've added an `exit()` and also tried `die()` and the page still loads with the connection error. Any ideas where to look? I've never worked with Drupal, just been thrown in the deep end.